# bash delete script don't work

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

i have a bash script that should all files that are not .avi, .mp4 and .mkv.

This is what i tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(find /home/mattia/test/ -type f -name '*.*')

for f in $FILES
do
        ext=${f#*.}
        echo $ext
        if [[ "$ext" != "mp4" || "$ext" != "mkv" || "$ext" != "avi" ]]; then
                rm -f $f
                echo deleted
        fi
done
```

But this script deletes all files.

Comment: you need && instead of ||

Comment: ***... if ext not match mp4 OR ext not match mkv OR ...*** So yes I think this will always be true!

Comment: @RohitS true thx

Comment: a file wont be having multiple extension..your comparison and use of "if" is wrong!..so you dont need either of them but you want if not any of them..

Comment: @RohitS yeah sorry I delete my comment after 1 second  I realised what a bullshit I wrote

Comment: @MattiaMancina thats ok..no need for apologies... cheers :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from changing `||` to `&&`, the script is fragile,
for example it won't work if any of the files contains spaces.
In general it's not safe to store the output of `find` in a variable for looping, so this practice should be avoided.

In any case, you don't need a loop, `find` can do this all by itself, and safer:

```
find /home/mattia/test/ -type f ! \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' \) -print -delete
```

Note that instead of `!`, you could use the more intuitive `-not`,
but keep in mind that it is not POSIX compliant.

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ not in Bash. But just to be safer, I changed it to the more intuitive and readable `-not`, thanks for the nudge

Comment: @MattiaMancina I added `-type f` condition to restrict to files only, see my updated answer

Comment: @janos thank you very much. Now i have the script I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is logical that

```
[[ "$ext" != "mp4" || "$ext" != "mkv" || "$ext" != "avi" ]]
```

is always true. For example: if the file name is `movie.avi`, `"$ext" != "mp4"` will be true and therefore the complete if will always be true.

As always, there are many ways to solve this. Janos did it in `find`; an alternative would be:

```
find /find /home/mattia/test/ -type f -name '*.*'home/mattia/test/ -type f -name '*.*' |
  egrep -v '.mp4$|.mkv$|.avi$' |
  xargs rm
```

Or, in your loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=$(find /home/mattia/test/ -type f -name '*.*')

for f in $FILES
do
    ext=${f#*.}
    echo $ext
    case "$ext" in        
    (mp4) echo "Keeping $f"
          ;;
    (mkv) echo "Not deleting $f"
          ;;
    (avi) echo "Holding on to $f"
          ;;
    (*)   rm -f "$f"
          echo "deleted $f"
          ;;
    esac
done
```

(which should work as long as your file names don't have spaces)

Or sorting-out the if-condition

```
[[ ! ( "$ext" = "mp4" || "$ext" = "mkv" || "$ext" = "avi" ) ]]
```